# ValueError with NLTK

Tags: python, nltk

Using NLTK, I'm trying to print a line of text if the last word of the line has an "NN" POS tag, but I'm getting:  "ValueError: too many values to unpack" on the following code.  Any ideas why?  Thanks in advance.

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

def end_of_line():
    filename = raw_input("Please enter a text file.> ")
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            linewords = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(line)
            lw_tagged = nltk.tag.pos_tag(linewords)
            last_lw_tagged = lw_tagged.pop()
            for (word, tag) in last_lw_tagged:
                if tag == "NN":
                    print line

end_of_line()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/private/var/folders/ly/n5ph6rcx47q8zz_j4pcj3b880000gn/T/Cleanup At Startup/endofline-477697124.590.py", line 15, in <module>
end_of_line()
File "/private/var/folders/ly/n5ph6rcx47q8zz_j4pcj3b880000gn/T/Cleanup At Startup/endofline-477697124.590.py", line 11, in end_of_line
for (word, tag) in last_lw_tagged:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
logout
```

Comment: You should copy the complete traceback and include it in your question.  I'm guessing its not the print statement.

Comment: @joelgoldstick Thank you.  I apologize:  This is my first time posting a question.  I added the traceback above.

Comment: Ok, so print last_lw_tagged before your for loop and see what it is.  It is apparently not a tuple

Comment: @joelgoldstick That's the strange thing, I think that last_lw_tagged is working properly -- it outputs in the format I expect, e.g.: ('sleep', 'NN')

Comment: how about getting rid of the for loop and doing if last_lw_tagged[1] == 'NN'

Comment: @joelgoldstick That works! It's much simpler, too.  Thanks 1,000,000!  I sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: you can select my answer if you like!

Comment: @joelgoldstick Sure thing!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
for (word, tag) in last_lw_tagged:
   if tag == "NN":
```

Do this:

```
if last_lw_tagged[1] == "NN:
```